# I haven't seen any code like this before, what is it?

Tags: c++, grammar

Can anyone tells me why this is allowed in c++, and what is it?

```
const char* a = (10, "What");
```

Comment: It's the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)

Comment: It's a pointless use of the comma operator.  Whoever wrote the code should be dragged outside and made to read a C++ tutorial before being allowed back in anywhere near the codebase.

Comment: Note that there's a comma operator in the question title too.  The LHS of the operator is ignorable; it doesn't do anything useful and could be thrown away.  The RHS is where the action is.

Comment: This is the same as const char* a = "what";

Comment: I've to admit that this looked quite surprising and confusing to me as well. (...though I know the comma operator and have used it from time to time.) ;-) Maybe, it's the fact that this is simply non-sense and hence looks that unfamiliar even although it compiles.